# Java: Issue with classes

Tags: java, static-members

I have following code

```
class Demo {
    static int a = 0;
    static int b = 1;
    static {
        a = ++b;
    }

    void gam(int x) {
        a = a * x;
        b = b * x;
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo d1 = new Demo();
        Demo d2 = new Demo();
        d1.a++;
        d2.a--;
        System.out.println(d1.a + " " + d1.b + " " + d2.a + " " + d2.b);
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out why d1.a is 2. Shouldn't it be 3? Since `a=++b` makes it 2 and `d1.a++` makes it 3?

Answer (score 10):

The variable `a` is `static`, so there is only one `a` for all instances of `Demo`.  It starts off as `0`, and the `static` initializer sets it to `++b`, or `2`.  Then, `d1.a++` increments it to `3`, but `d2.a--` decrements the *same* `a` back down to `2`.

Answer (score 0):

`d1.a` is a static member field, so it should be accessed not via the instance. It should accessed via: `Demo.a`.

And by the way, `d1.a` and `d2.a` refer to the same static member field, so the increment of `a` in `d1.a++` is "roll-backed" with the decrement: `d2.a--`.